# Span value disappear after click

Tags: jquery

When user choose an option from the drop-down list, the selected option (text) is displayed in a span (id="myoption")
But, after click on submit button, the span value disappear.

My html code:

```
<div class="card-header py-3 d-flex flex-row align-items-center justify-content-between">
  <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">
  Generare heatmap pentru: Current&nbsp;Direction > anul 2017 > perioada:
  <span id="myoption" style="margin-left:230px;"></span>
  </h6>
  </div>

  <form name="add" method="post">
   <select class="form-control dropdown" id="dd" name="select_days" style="width:350px;margin-left:20px;">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecteaza o perioada:</option>
   <option value="1,2,3">1 Dec - 3 Dec</option>
   <option value="4,5,6">4 Dec - 6 Dec</option>
   <option value="7,8,9">7 Dec - 9 Dec</option>
   <option value="10,11,12">10 Dec - 12 Dec</option>
   <option value="13,14,15">13 Dec - 15 Dec</option>
   <option value="16,17,18">16 Dec - 18 Dec</option>
   <option value="19,20,21">19 Dec - 21 Dec</option>
   <option value="22,23,24">22 Dec - 24 Dec</option>
   <option value="25,26,27">25 Dec - 27 Dec</option>
   <option value="28,29,30">28 Dec - 30 Dec</option>


  </select>
  <br />
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Generare Plot" style="margin-left:20px;">
  </form>
```

The JS code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $( ".dropdown" ).change(function() {
        var myopt =  $( "#dd option:selected" ).text();
        $("#myoption").text(myopt);
     });

     $("input.btn btn-primary").click(function(event){
       var xxx = $('span#myoption').text();
       $("#myoption").text(xxx);
       event.preventDefault();
    });
  });
```

I look forward to any tips.

Comment: **always check your selectors** - `$("input.btn btn-primary")` will not select anything, so your submit is not cancelled.

Answer (score -1):

After cliking on submit button the form is getting submitted and it's reloading the page. so instead of form submit you can use Ajax call to submit the form.

it will work when you will change input type to **type="button"** instaed of **type="submit"** then create **ajax call** to submit the form data.